# AWS CloudFront Access-Control-Allow-Origin and Signed Cookie/Urls

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront

I'm stuck with a CORS at S3+Cloudfront+Signed Urls.

My use cases is:

First story (successful):

1. I have an Amazon S3 bucket with a Cloudfront. Files are accessible by the `DOMAIN1/file` link
2. I write a simple test JS script to get file from DOMAIN1 and put it at the `DOMAIN2/test.html`
3. I'm able to get file successfully. **CORS is fine**.

Second case (successful too):

1. I restrict Cloud Front distribution by using Signed Url.
2. At first I tried is to access a file at DOMAIN1 **without** Signature. Got an Access denied. It's ok, since request is not signed.
3. I've created a signed URL and **able to download** the file successfully.

Third case (failed)

1. I put signed url (from 2nd case) to the `DOMAIN2/test.html` test script
2. And always got a `No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header` error.

So Cloudfront is not sending a header in case of restricted distribution.

CORS xml is:

```
<CORSConfiguration xmlns="http://s3.amazonaws.com/doc/2006-03-01/">
<CORSRule>
    <AllowedOrigin>http://*</AllowedOrigin>
    <AllowedOrigin>https://*</AllowedOrigin>
    <AllowedMethod>GET</AllowedMethod>
    <AllowedMethod>HEAD</AllowedMethod>
    <MaxAgeSeconds>10</MaxAgeSeconds>
    <AllowedHeader>*</AllowedHeader>
</CORSRule>
```

It must be some issue in the CloudFront/S3/IAM settings. How I can fix it?

Comment: It would be a lot easier to understand exactly what you are reporting if you could capture the request and response headers from the failed case.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like a solution was to setup a correct access rights to the S3 bucket. Instead the "Everyone" access, need an "Any AWS authenticated user" or "Cloudfront appropriate user".

Answer (score -1):

I went to `Cloudfront Distributions -> MYPRIVATECLOUDFRONTID -> Behaviors` and added the Following:

```
Path Pattern = path/to/my/file.ext

Forward Headers = Whitelist
```

And added to `Whitelist Header: Origin`

Don't forget to uncheck the option `Restrict Viewer Access (Use Signed URLs or
Signed Cookies)` - for me, it was marked to not restrict even though I have marked the whole cache to be restricted.

My next step is to automatically set this whitelist on demand.